# Why my data-binding annotation(@BindingAdapter("imageURL")) doesn't work?

Tags: android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding, imageurl

I've written my custom recyclerView and have got a problem. But when I wrote an annotation to mark a setter for my imageView I got a compilation error.
Here are the source code and errors.

Error:
***Cannot find a setter for <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView app:imageURL> that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'***
***If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.***

Setter code:

```kotlin
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import java.lang.Exception

class BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("imageURL")//compilation error
    fun setImageURL(imageView: ImageView, URL: String?) {
        imageView.alpha = 0f
        try {
            Picasso.get().load(URL).noFade().into(imageView, object : Callback {
                override fun onSuccess() {
                    imageView.animate().setDuration(300).alpha(1f).start()
                }
                override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                }
            })
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        }

    }
}
```

ImageView xml code:

```xml
 <data>

        <variable
            name="eventShow"
            type="course.ru.qsearcher.models.Event" />
    </data>
........
 <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageEvent"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:imageURL="@{eventShow.imagePath}"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/_4sdp" />
```

Event is a data class with some fields like the title of an event,  description, image URL, and so on.

[сode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLryO.png)

[xml usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cComB.png)

[url-field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFfDo.png)

Comment: Please do not format questions as links.

Comment: please rephrase everything, where possible, with complete code blocks. Even if it makes it a little long _especially_ as your links are to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't add the Kotlin plugin to my gradle file

```kotlin
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
```

That solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:imageURL` to `imageURL`, the `android:` prefix is for built-in attribute like `android:text`.

And use it like `imageURL` or `app:imageURL` in your `ImageView`.

Comment: @alf3ratz Also remove the `=` when you use that attribute, you don't need to the 2-way binding I guess.